# Apex - Loop Through List and Set of IDs

Tags: apex, list, loop, set

I have a set of IDs and a soql to get list of accounts for those IDs:

```
Set<ID> setOfIDs  = new Set<ID>{//AccountIDs};

List<CustomObj> lstCustObjDetails = [Select ID, Name, Record__c,Account__c  from CustomObj where Account__c IN setOfIDs ] ; 

//Check size of the list for all accounts
System.Debug(lstCustObjDetails.size());
```

How to check the size of the list for each account?

I want to create a Map and loop through each ID in setOfIDs and check the list size for each Account__c.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by "list size for each Account__c".  Assuming that there are CustomObj records with values in those selected fields, your query returns one list of CustomObj records; each 'entry' in that list is one CustomObj record which contains one value in each of `ID`, `Name`, `Record__c` and `Account__c` fields.  `Account__c` is not a list and would not have a size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question, as stated, isn't very clear. Given the query you have though, I'm assuming your question is something like

- I have a custom object which has a relationship (lookup or master-detail) to `Account`
- I have a collection of Account Ids
- I want to know how many of my custom object records are related to each Account

If that's the case, then the simplest way to do this in code would be to use a SOQL query with [aggregate functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm).

Using `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`, you can have SOQL do most of the heavy lifting. Such a query would look like

```
List<AggregateResult> results = [
    SELECT COUNT(Id) numberOfChildren, AccountId 
    FROM Custom_Object__c 
    WHERE AccountId IN :setOfIds 
    GROUP BY AccountId];
```

As you might be able to read from the query, it counts the number of records in `Custom_Object__c` which have an AccountId in the set of Ids you're working with. By grouping the results by AccountId, you get what you're looking for, the count of records for each unique AccountId you provided.

When you use `GROUP BY`, you get a `List<AggregateResult>` from the query instead of a `List<SObject>`.
You need to use `.get()` to fetch values from an `AggregateResult`, and the result is an `Object`, which you'll need to type-cast to really do anything with.

The "numberOfChildren" in the SELECT clause is an *alias*, which can only be used in conjunction with an Aggregate Function.

Given that `results` variable, the loop you'd use to extract results from it would look something like

```
for(AggregateResult ar :results){
    Id accountId = (Id)ar.get('AccountId');
    // The alias used in the query is the same thing you use to get the result
    // If you don't use an alias, you'd instead use 'expr0', 'expr1', etc...
    //   (the automatically assigned alias, indexed from 0, and incremented
    //   for each aggregate function used, assigned from left to right)
    Integer count = (Integer)ar.get('numberOfChildren');

    system.debug(String.format('The Account with Id {0} has {1} child(ren)',
        new List<Object>{
            accountId,
            count
        }
    );
}
```